# 'pyodbc.Cursor' object has no attribute 'fast_executemany'

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I have a problem, I have a web app that is using `fast_executemany`
in order to insert into the database. When running it on localhost it works with no problem, but when deploying it to Azure, I get

> `'pyodbc.Cursor'` object has no attribute `'fast_executemany'`

I am using

- Python 2.7
- AZURE SQL server DB
- pyodbc==4.0.24

The web app is stored in Azure

Comment: According to the `pyodbc` wiki on GitHub, the cursor attribute `fast_executemany` is "new in version 4.0.19". Looks very much as though your deployment target has an older version. https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#fast_executemany. I suggest you amend your code to do a version check and skip over `fast_executemany= True`.

Answer (score 0):

Azure provides us a tutorial about [how to use Python to connect to an Azure SQL database and use Transact-SQL statements to query data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-python).

And if we want to use `fast_executemany` attribute, we must set `cursor.fast_executemany = True`

We can modify the sample like this:

```
import pyodbc
server = '<server>.database.windows.net'
database = '<database>'
username = '<username>'
password = '<password>'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.fast_executemany = True
cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 20 pc.Name as CategoryName, p.name as ProductName FROM [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] pc JOIN [SalesLT].[Product] p ON pc.productcategoryid = p.productcategoryid")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

I think you can try again. If you still have other issue, please let me know, and I will do my best to help you.

Hope this can helps you.

Comment: I am doing exactly the same :  driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';PORT=1433;SERVER='+server+';PORT=1443;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)      newcursor = cnxn.cursor() newcursor.fast_executemany = True
    newcursor.executemany(sqlupdates,args)
    newcursor.commit()
    newcursor.close()